# adding menue or buttons for Top Tab bar in objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I want to add 4 buttons or 4 menues in my TOP TAB BAR or top navigation bar, would you please help me that how can I do that should I do that via interface or programmatically and how?

Thanks in advance!
I'm really new to the iOS!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If using iOS 5, you can use the rightBarButtonItems/leftBarButtonItems  property of the nav bar.
Just create an array of UIBarButtonItems, and assign that to the appropriate side.

```
UIBarButtonItem *button1= [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction target:self action:@selector(methodOne:)];
UIBarButtonItem *button2= [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction target:self action:@selector(methodTwo:)];
UIBarButtonItem *button3= [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction target:self action:@selector(methodthree:)];
UIBarButtonItem *button4= [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction target:self action:@selector(methodFour:)];

NSArray *buttons = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:button1,button2,button3,button4,nil];
```

Then, to put these on the left side of the navbar:

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItems = buttons;
```

Or to put them on the right side:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = buttons;
```

You can also use the following to add spaces between your buttons:

```
UIBarButtonItem *flexible = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil]
NSArray *buttons = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:button1,flexible,button2,flexible,button3,flexible button4,nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

It's as simple as assigning [UIBarButtonItem](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html)s to your view controller's implied navigationController instance.  Forgive the technical jargon, perhaps some code will make up for it:

```
//left
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]init];
//right
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]init];
```

Note that this *won't* work if your root view controller isn't a [UINavigationController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html).